# drupal 6 multitab with ajax content

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I just want to show multitab on each node page. and want to pass node id to each tab. each tab should load content either via ajax if noscript it should load via url

Please help me with this any tutorial or reference

Thanks,

Edvin

Answer (score 0):

Create a **View** that use the node id as an argument. Then you may use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to display your view at the desired nod, using tabs style.

Let me know if that was enough to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

[this module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) will do exact thing , though its more like an api, you have to create link using the function this modules provides .For example

```
l_ajax("add page", "node/add/page", "#content-content")
```

**OR**

```
<a class="ajax_link" href="node/add/page" rel="#content-content">Add page</a>
```